# How to configure access points and dhcp ranges?

Tags: dhcp, static-ip-address, access-point

I have a Thomson ST585V6 router and 2 TRENDnet TEW-636APB Wireless Access Points. And I have 3 devices that need a static IP address. All the other devices need to have their IP adreess assigned with DHCP. Here is what I did:

In each of the 3 devices that need static IP I assigned the static IPs 192.168.1.64, 192.168.1.65 and 192.168.1.66. Then I assigned statics IPs to the two access points 192.168.1.67 and 192.168.1.68. I also made this access points DHCP Servers with DHCP pool addresses

- 192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.150 (one of them)
- 192.168.1.151 - 192.168.1.200 (the other one)

I then assigned my DHCP pool addresses from 192.168.1.69 to 192.168.1.200 for my Thomson router.

Right now everything is working just fine. My question is I am not quire sure how is the DHCP range on the access points working. Are they aware of the DHCP  pool on the Thompson router?, is it possible that one access point assigns .100 and so does the Thomson router?. This of course would not be good at all, since some devices communicate with each other.

Is the best option to have the 2 Access Points get their IP via DHCP from the Thompson Router and having as the only DHCP server the Thomson Router?. What would you do?. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I decided to have only one dhcp server and assign all devices static addresses.